# Beginner question - factor variables (Tidyverse)

Tags: r, select, tidyverse, dplyr, ggcorrplot

I think this is a simple question for most but I am new to r and was hoping someone could help.

How can I create a new factor variable for levels of a variable (e.g. 0 = no, 1= yes). Then how do I put this into a new data frame?

So far I have been playing with the 'select' and 'mutate' functions but cannot get somewhere that I can create a correlation plot with the variable.

Thanks in advance! I slammed my laptop shut too many times over this!

Comment: ie. This is the prompt I am given: First create a new factor variable for the levels of the variable smoke (Note that 0 means no, 1 means yes.). Create a new data frame with the variables that we will use in the analysis. Use the tidyverse only to do this.

Comment: can you share a reproducible example please

Comment: Sure:  First create a new factor variable called supply for the levels of the variable smoke (Note that 0 means no, 1 means yes.). Create a new data frame with the variables that we will use in the analysis. Use the tidyverse only to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  fct = rep(0:1, each=100) %>% factor(),
  x =rep(1:100, 2), 
  y = rnorm(200)
)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y, col=fct))+geom_line()
```

Read this carefully:
https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/factors.pdf